# Press OK in window security popup in webbrowser

Tags: c#, .net

i need to press the ok button when this popup appear automatically
i tried with sendkeys but didn't work
this is the popup:

[image: Windows Security popup ssl certificate example]

Comment: Press OK from where?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: from webbrowser ,using code with visual studio.

Comment: @MethodMan i need to do this automatically.

Comment: @frferergthyttyhhyt: (Welsh?) I reckon it would be easier to circumvent the dialog from being invoked in the first place. Otherwise, it would be a very hacky and kludgy circumvention of built-in Windows security, it seems.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588473/automating-the-choose-a-digital-certificate-dialog

Answer (score 3):

Doing this from a web browser is never going to happen, that is a serious security violation. The reason a popup is shown is so that a user can choose to not accept a certificate that they don't want.

Comment: And there is a way to do this without webbrowser or using dllimport to modify the running procces of windows?

Comment: You're missing the point of this answer. It's a security issue. Even if you could easily do this, you should not want to. What if you accidentally started automatically confirming all kinds of random certificates?

Comment: What are you trying to automate? The acceptance of the certificate on anybody's computer just by them visiting your website or are you trying to automate some in house process? I'm trying to understand a legitimate reason for this but so far I'm not seeing one.